# OpenCV: распознание нечёткой четырехугольной поверхности на фото

Tags: opencv

Всем привет,

работаю над хобби-проектом, где пытаюсь определить 4х-угольную поверхность (например стол) на произвольном фото при помощи OpenCV (**Python**, Java или C++).

Выделил нужную область по цвету, получил маску и передал её в функцию `cv2.findContours` (в данном случае `Canny` не нужен)

```
cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnt = sorted(cnts, key = cv2.contourArea, reverse = True)[0]
peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True)
approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt,0.02*peri, True)
if len(approx) == 4:
    cv2.drawContours(mask, [approx], -1, (255, 0, 0), 2)
```

в результате получился не совсем точный контур:
[image: cv2.findContours]

используя `cv2.HoughLines` удалось получить 4 прямых линии, которые точно описывают поверхность:

```
edged = cv2.Canny(mask, 10, 200)
hLines = cv2.HoughLines(edged, 2, np.pi/180, 200)
lines = []
for rho,theta in hLines[0]:
    a = np.cos(theta)
    b = np.sin(theta)
    x0 = a*rho
    y0 = b*rho
    x1 = int(x0 + 1000*(-b))
    y1 = int(y0 + 1000*(a))
    x2 = int(x0 - 1000*(-b))
    y2 = int(y0 - 1000*(a))
    cv2.line(mask, (x1,y1), (x2,y2), (255, 0, 0), 2)
    lines.append([[x1,y1],[x2,y2]])
```

[image: HoughLines]

Есть ли какой нибудь способ подогнать контуры `cv2.findContours` так, чтобы они отражали реальную поверхность?

Другим решением было бы определить 4 точки пересечения прямых, полученных из `cv2.HoughLines` (используя школьные формулы пока не получилось их вычислить, так что любые советы приветствуются :)

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Заранее скажу, что все темы в англ версии просмотрел вдоль и поперек.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Спасибо @gbg за подсказку.

Перед тем, как найти точки пересечения линий, полученных из `cv2.HoughLines`, нужно учесть несколько моментов:

1. Самое главное - подобрать нужные параметры функции `HoughLines`, так как она может вернуть от 0 до бесконечного количества линий, когда нам нужно только 4.
2. Так как мы не знаем в каком порядку эти линии идут, нужно сравнить каждую с остальными
3. Из-за перспективы параллельные линии больше не параллельны, поэтому каждая линия будет иметь точку пересечения с другими. Простой способ решения - отфильтровать координаты, которые расположены за пределами фото (матрицы). Но может случиться так, что ненужные пересечение будет и в пределах фото.
4. Нужно отсортировать координаты. В зависимости от задачи можно сделать это по разному

В итоге дана матрица со значениями [rho и theta](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html) для каждой линии полученных из `HoughLines`, нужно решить систему уравнений для всех линий попарно

[image: система уравнений]

```
def intersections(edged):
    # высота и ширина фото с контуром, полученным Canny
    h, w = edged.shape

    hl = cv2.HoughLines(edged,2,np.pi/180,190)[0]
    # количество линий. если не равно 4, нужно изменить параметры
    n = hl.shape[0]    

    # матрица со значениями cos(theta) и sin(theta) для каждой линии
    T = np.zeros((n,2),dtype=np.float32)
    # вектор со значениями rho
    R = np.zeros((n),dtype=np.float32)

    T[:,0] = np.cos(hl[:,1])
    T[:,1] = np.sin(hl[:,1])
    R = hl[:,0]

    # количество комбинаций всех линий
    c = n*(n-1)/2
    # матрица с полученными координатами (x,y)
    XY = np.zeros((c,2))
    # перебираем все варианты
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(i+1, n):
            XY[i+j-1, :] = np.linalg.inv(T[[i,j],:]).dot(R[[i,j]])

    # отфильтровываем координаты за пределами фото
    XY = XY[(XY[:,0] > 0) & (XY[:,0] <= w) & (XY[:,1] > 0) & (XY[:,1] <= h)]
    # XY = order_points(XY) # хорошо бы их отсортировать
    return XY
```

В итоге результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Поиск пересечения прямых - дело нехитрое.

Рассматриваем параметры первой прямой как theta1, rho1, параметры второй прямой как theta2, rho2

Тогда декартовы координаты (X,Y) точки их пересечения можно найти, решив СЛАУ

```
cos(theta1)*X+sin(theta1)*Y-rho1=0
cos(theta2)*X+sin(theta2)*Y-rho2=0
```

[Источник](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html)

Comment: спасибо! очень помогло. в документации ни слово не понятно, что такое rho и с трудом понятно, что такое theta

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghlines/py_houghlines.html - второй абзац раздела Theory содержит картинку и уравнение.